# Generate hashing code (saved in int) from string with C langage

Tags: c, hash

I want to generate a hashing code as int from a string.

Are there predefined algoritms for that? are there implementation for that algorithms in C?

```
char name[100]="langage c"
```

Generate a hash code for that `name` buffer into an integer variable

```
int hash_code;
```

something like that

```
int algo_hash(char *name) {
    //hash algorithme
}
hash_code = algo_hash(name);
```

Looking for a simple code as such as possible

Comment: There are tons of hash functions available.

Comment: You need a hashing function. Try Googling/searching stackoverflow for that, there are many and they all have different properties.

Comment: You need to look into hash functions. Of course the number cannot be unique if the set of strings is unrestricted, since no `int` has as many bits as a `char [100]`.

Comment: hashcode doesn't guarantee an unique value, so the issue is how to generate and guarantee an unique value

Comment: @EllouzeAnis - If you want a unique `int` for an unrestricted set of strings, it's not possible (see unwind's comment). If you want a unique set of `int`s (more then one) or `long long`s or if you have a restricted set of strings allowed then there's a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

The general technique is called "[hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)". If you have a know list of strings, you can use the tool [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html) to generate a perfect hash function for them.

If the strings are random, this isn't possible in the general case with these constraints. You could use an SHA-1 hash algorithm but that produces a 160 bit number from a string and there is no 100% guarantee that the values are unique (collisions with SHA-1 are just very unlikely but not impossible).

Comment: hashcode doesn't guarantee an unique value, so the issue is how to generate and guarantee an unique value

Comment: Read the documentation to gperf, please. Also, hash functions are the best solution so far. Unless you have a database or can assign each string a unique ID manually...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is to implement [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Still it will not be unique - I doubt you will be able to avoid collisions.

Comment: if the input set is known beforehand, one can generate a perfect hash using gperf.

Comment: If the input is known beforehand and is reasonably small.

Comment: gperf can handle sets as large as 15000 elements, it really depends on what is in the set.

Comment: 15000 is not much really. For instance if you have all 8 character stings formed from the latin alphabet you have 208827064576 strings  which waaay more.